# How come that PyQt's icon isn't as sharp as it should be?

Tags: python, user-interface, icons, pyqt, ubuntu-unity

I'm using Python 2.7 with PyQt. I'm setting a `QtGui.QMainWindow()` icon by using

```
self.setWindowIcon(QtGui.QIcon("icon.ico"))
```

Whenever I run my program, the icon looks very blurry, or pixelated. This is not what I want. I want the icon to be as sharp as Ubuntu's usual applications. To compare, I've made a .desktop file with the `Icon` parameter pointing to `icon.ico`. This one looks much sharper than PyQt's icon. Please compare. The icon you should focus on is the blue world map icon.

How can I make PyQt's icon as sharp as the other?

[image: The blurry one]
[image: The sharp one]

Comment: Same problem here, ¿have you found a solution?

Comment: Not yet, if you find one, post it by clicking the _Answer Question_ button :-)